# Javascript Reg ex help

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Could you please provide regular expression for identifying all divs in javascript whose id begins with *com*

```
e.g <div id="_com_1">
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you have jQuery on the page, you can use `$('div[id^="_com_"]')` which is by the way a valid CSS3 selector: `div[id^="_com_"]`.

I would recommend using that instead of regexing through the entire HTML, which might find false positives in text or html comments.

Comment: This also works without jQuery in modern browsers via `document.querySelector('div[id^="_com_"]')`, so I don't think it's that useless an answer. It just depends on context, and there wasn't much of that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
  if(/^_com/.test(divs[i].id)){
    //do something
  }
}
```

This assumes the divs are already a part of the DOM.

Comment: +1 but consider testing like `if(/^_com_\d+$/.test(divs[i].id))`

Comment: @maerics thanks I didn't mean to have the 1 there.  I wish the OP was a little clearer on what the different inputs could be.

Answer (score 0):

`/^_com/.test("_com_1")` <-- evaluates to true

would work for this situation, but for simply beginning with com you need

`/^com/.test("_com_1")` <-- evaluates to false